# Mysql gaps and islands issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

Would like to count number of rows between occurrence where total number of score is above 60, and count number of rows where this occurrence doesn't happened.
For example 5th and 6th game will end up with more then 60, so will count 5 rows with not 60 and 2 rows with 60.

I would like something like this:

```
type                 count
no-60-gap            5
yes-60-island        1
no-60-gap            3
yes-60-island        2
```

I have simple database of basketball games. Rough example below

```
id, home,    score_home,  away,     score_away, round
1,  team_1,  33,          team_2,   23,         1 
2,  team_4,  31,          team_1,   33,         1 
3,  team_2,  36,          team_5,   53,         2 
4,  team_5,  35,          team_1,   63,         2 
5,  team_7,  31,          team_8,   53,         3 
6,  team_2,  30,          team_1,   43,         3 
7,  team_1,  39,          team_3,   13,         4
```

Was google-ing out this issues and I have end up trying to solve my problem with gaps and islands.

This is my solution but it not working. Idea was just to reset gap/island to 0 when it doesn't happened. 
I am kind a new in this.

```
SET @gap :=0; SET @island :=0;
SELECT 
@gap, 
@island
FROM (
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN (score_home + score_away) >= 60 THEN @island:=@island+1 
    WHEN (score_home + score_away) >= 60 THEN @gap:=0 
END,
CASE 
    WHEN (score_home + score_away) < 60 THEN @island:=0 
    WHEN (score_home + score_away) < 60 THEN @gap:=@gap+1
END
FROM basket

) AS games
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Could you provide some sample output to match your input?

Comment: @jeremytwfortune They are all zeros. Not sure is my approach good at all.

Comment: No, not what your code generates. Provide what you *want*.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune sorry, didn't understand you, I have edit my question. I would just like to count rows between there were no 60(for how long in row count), to count rows where there were 60(for how long in a row count). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're after something like this...

```
SELECT v,flag,COUNT(*)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT flag
            , CASE WHEN @prev = flag THEN @v:=@v ELSE @v:=@v+1 END v
            , @prev:=flag
         FROM 
            ( SELECT *, score_home + score_away >= 60 flag FROM my_table ) x
         JOIN
            ( SELECT @prev:=NULL,@v:=0) vars
        ORDER
           BY id
     ) n
 GROUP
    BY v,flag;
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for late response, COUNT(*) is an island, and gap is flag? v is just index number? I am still little confuse how this works, but will figure out. Tnx again.

Comment: Remove the COUNT(*) and the GROUP BY, and see what you get. Does that help at all?

Comment: I am not saying that you query is not good, I am just trying to understand how it is working, and what is what, so I could learn something new here :) I have remove it, now it is more confusing. So flag is generally when score is more then 60. not sure what is v for?

Comment: I know. I was trying to help you look under the hood

Comment: Sorry again for late response, was busy. I got it now. Please post a link if you have any good tutorial that you would suggest. I have google it a lot of. Tnx again